# Multiple editexts validate if the field is with data with visibility in save button

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have read many post and have made all of the suggestions but none of them work. First of all the view of the button to save its setVisibility to GONE in the xml.

This is the full class:

```
public class AdminAddCar extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.image_add_admin_layout)
    ImageView imageAddAdminLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.add_car_photo_admin)
    ImageButton addCarPhotoAdmin;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_marca)
    EditText edMarca;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_chasis)
    EditText edChasis;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_color)
    EditText edColor;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_kilometraje)
    EditText edKilometraje;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_modelo)
    EditText edModelo;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_motor)
    EditText edMotor;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_placa)
    EditText edPlaca;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_precio)
    EditText edPrecio;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_referencia)
    EditText edReferencia;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_sucursal)
    EditText edSucursal;

    String uId;
    String image;
    String marca;
    String chasis;
    String color;
    String kilometraje;
    String modelo;
    String placa;
    String motor;
    String precio;
    String referencia;
    String sucursal;



    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    private static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER = 2;
    @BindView(R.id.adm_boton_guardar)
    Button admBotonGuardar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.admin_add_layout);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        /**
         * Implement the photo picker
         */
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Automoviles");
        firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference().child("carUploads");



        addCarPhotoAdmin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Fire an intent to show an image picker
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);
            }
        });

        admBotonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GuardarAutomoviles();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            Log.i("ImageUri", "This is the ImageUri ----------------------->:" + selectedImageUri);
            final StorageReference photoRef = storageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
            photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(
                    this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                            while (!urlTask.isSuccessful()) ;
                            final Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();
                            image =downloadUrl.toString();
                            Log.i("TAG","This is the image:---->"+image);

                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    public void GuardarAutomoviles() {

//        if(image!=null) {

         String objMarca = edMarca.getText().toString().trim();
        int objChasis = Integer.parseInt(edChasis.getText().toString().trim());
         String objColor = edColor.getText().toString().trim();
         int objKilometraje = Integer.parseInt(edKilometraje.getText().toString().trim());
         int objModelo = Integer.parseInt(edModelo.getText().toString().trim());
         String objPlaca = edPlaca.getText().toString().trim();
         String objMotor = edMotor.getText().toString().trim();
        int objPrecio = Integer.parseInt(edPrecio.getText().toString().trim());
        String objReferencia = edReferencia.getText().toString().trim();
        String objSucursal = edSucursal.getText().toString().trim();



        edMarca.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edChasis.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edColor.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edKilometraje.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edModelo.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edPlaca.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edMotor.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edPrecio.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edReferencia.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edSucursal.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);


            Automoviles autosAdmin = new Automoviles(objMarca, objPlaca, objReferencia, objColor, image,
                    objModelo, objPrecio, objChasis, objKilometraje, objMotor, objSucursal);


                databaseReference.push().setValue(autosAdmin);
                String key = databaseReference.getKey();
                Toast.makeText(this, "save ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        private TextWatcher adminTextwatcher=new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                marca = edMarca.getText().toString().trim();
                chasis = edChasis.getText().toString().trim();
                 color = edColor.getText().toString().trim();
                kilometraje = edKilometraje.getText().toString().trim();
                 modelo = edModelo.getText().toString().trim();
                 placa = edPlaca.getText().toString().trim();
                 motor = edMotor.getText().toString().trim();
                 precio = edPrecio.getText().toString().trim();
                 referencia = edReferencia.getText().toString().trim();
                sucursal = edSucursal.getText().toString().trim();

                if(!chasis.matches("")
                        &&!chasis.matches("")
                        &&!color.matches("")
                        &&!kilometraje.matches("")
                        &&!modelo.matches("")
                        &&!placa.matches("")
                        &&!motor.matches("")
                        &&!precio.matches("")
                        &&!referencia.matches("")
                        &&!sucursal.matches("")){
                    admBotonGuardar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        };

    }
```

When i emulate the app the save button is GONE but when i fill the editText fields the button its supposed to appear! but this just doesnt happen!.

This is the updated code:

```
 public void GuardarAutomoviles() {

//        if(image!=null) {

        String objMarca = edMarca.getText().toString().trim();
        int objChasis = Integer.parseInt(edChasis.getText().toString().trim());
        String objColor = edColor.getText().toString().trim();
        int objKilometraje = Integer.parseInt(edKilometraje.getText().toString().trim());
        int objModelo = Integer.parseInt(edModelo.getText().toString().trim());
        String objPlaca = edPlaca.getText().toString().trim();
        String objMotor = edMotor.getText().toString().trim();
        int objPrecio = Integer.parseInt(edPrecio.getText().toString().trim());
        String objReferencia = edReferencia.getText().toString().trim();
        String objSucursal = edSucursal.getText().toString().trim();


        edMarca.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edChasis.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edColor.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edKilometraje.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edModelo.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edPlaca.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edMotor.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edPrecio.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edReferencia.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edSucursal.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);



        if (!chasis.isEmpty()
                || !color.isEmpty()
                || !kilometraje.isEmpty()
                || !modelo.isEmpty()
                || !placa.isEmpty()
                || !motor.isEmpty()
                ||!precio.isEmpty()
                || !referencia.isEmpty()
                || !sucursal.isEmpty()) {
            admBotonGuardar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        marca = edMarca.getText().toString().trim();
        chasis = edChasis.getText().toString().trim();
        color = edColor.getText().toString().trim();
        kilometraje = edKilometraje.getText().toString().trim();
        modelo = edModelo.getText().toString().trim();
        placa = edPlaca.getText().toString().trim();
        motor = edMotor.getText().toString().trim();
        precio = edPrecio.getText().toString().trim();
        referencia = edReferencia.getText().toString().trim();
        sucursal = edSucursal.getText().toString().trim();




            Automoviles autosAdmin = new Automoviles(objMarca, objPlaca, objReferencia, objColor, image,
                    objModelo, objPrecio, objChasis, objKilometraje, objMotor, objSucursal);


            databaseReference.push().setValue(autosAdmin);
            String key = databaseReference.getKey();
            Toast.makeText(this, "save ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `matches()` which is wrong. 
You should check the string object with `.isEmpty()`

Or you can also use `TextUtils.isEmpty(string)`

Comment: i used it with isEmpty and TextUtils.isEmpty(string) and it didnt work.

Comment: Try it on after text changed listener.

Comment: Update the Code with TextUtils and why are you checking this twice? 
 `if(!chasis.matches("")
                        &&!chasis.matches("")`

Comment: It still doesnt work! i tried to add TextUtils but it did work it was red. Someone suggested to use better || so i have for every validation                         || !motor.isEmpty()

Comment: You are making a silly mistake.  Update the code with TectUtils and I will check.

Comment: i cant make marca.TextUtils.isEmpty(); i will update the code

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this problem here ,is that i wasnt doing it in onCreate. so anyways i will post the answer this could help a lot of people !.

code:

```
package com.example.mac.udacitycapstonefinalproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.opengl.Visibility;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mac.udacitycapstonefinalproject.Model.Automoviles;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class AdminAddCar extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.image_add_admin_layout)
    ImageView imageAddAdminLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.add_car_photo_admin)
    ImageButton addCarPhotoAdmin;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_marca)
    EditText edMarca;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_chasis)
    EditText edChasis;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_color)
    EditText edColor;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_kilometraje)
    EditText edKilometraje;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_modelo)
    EditText edModelo;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_motor)
    EditText edMotor;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_placa)
    EditText edPlaca;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_precio)
    EditText edPrecio;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_referencia)
    EditText edReferencia;
    @BindView(R.id.ed_sucursal)
    EditText edSucursal;

    String uId;
    String image;
    String marca;
    String chasis;
    String color;
    String kilometraje;
    String modelo;
    String placa;
    String motor;
    String precio;
    String referencia;
    String sucursal;


    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    private static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER = 2;
    @BindView(R.id.adm_boton_guardar)
    Button admBotonGuardar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.admin_add_layout);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        /**
         * Implement the photo picker
         */
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Automoviles");
        firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference().child("carUploads");


        addCarPhotoAdmin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Fire an intent to show an image picker
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);
            }
        });

        admBotonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GuardarAutomoviles();
                finish();
            }
        });

        TextWatcher adminTextwatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                marca = edMarca.getText().toString().trim();
                chasis = edChasis.getText().toString().trim();
                color = edColor.getText().toString().trim();
                kilometraje = edKilometraje.getText().toString().trim();
                modelo = edModelo.getText().toString().trim();
                placa = edPlaca.getText().toString().trim();
                motor = edMotor.getText().toString().trim();
                precio = edPrecio.getText().toString().trim();
                referencia = edReferencia.getText().toString().trim();
                sucursal = edSucursal.getText().toString().trim();


                if (!chasis.isEmpty()
                        && !color.isEmpty()
                        && !kilometraje.isEmpty()
                        &&!modelo.isEmpty()
                        && !placa.isEmpty()
                        && !motor.isEmpty()
                        &&!precio.isEmpty()
                        && !referencia.isEmpty()
                        && !sucursal.isEmpty()) {
                    admBotonGuardar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    admBotonGuardar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


            }




            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        };


        edMarca.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edChasis.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edColor.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edKilometraje.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edModelo.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edPlaca.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edMotor.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edPrecio.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edReferencia.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);
        edSucursal.addTextChangedListener(adminTextwatcher);


    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            Log.i("ImageUri", "This is the ImageUri ----------------------->:" + selectedImageUri);
            final StorageReference photoRef = storageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
            photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(
                    this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                            while (!urlTask.isSuccessful()) ;
                            final Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();
                            image = downloadUrl.toString();
                            Log.i("TAG", "This is the image:---->" + image);

                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    public void GuardarAutomoviles() {

//        if(image!=null) {

        String objMarca = edMarca.getText().toString().trim();
        int objChasis = Integer.parseInt(edChasis.getText().toString().trim());
        String objColor = edColor.getText().toString().trim();
        int objKilometraje = Integer.parseInt(edKilometraje.getText().toString().trim());
        int objModelo = Integer.parseInt(edModelo.getText().toString().trim());
        String objPlaca = edPlaca.getText().toString().trim();
        String objMotor = edMotor.getText().toString().trim();
        int objPrecio = Integer.parseInt(edPrecio.getText().toString().trim());
        String objReferencia = edReferencia.getText().toString().trim();
        String objSucursal = edSucursal.getText().toString().trim();











            Automoviles autosAdmin = new Automoviles(objMarca, objPlaca, objReferencia, objColor, image,
                    objModelo, objPrecio, objChasis, objKilometraje, objMotor, objSucursal);


            databaseReference.push().setValue(autosAdmin);
            String key = databaseReference.getKey();
            Toast.makeText(this, "save ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```